# Cannot open file when passing file name as an argument to exe file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, exe

I am trying to run an  .exe file with 'c' and an input file name "input.txt" as arguments. Below is my code snippet:

```
import subprocess
filename = "C:\Python27\\application_rx_example\Debug\\input.txt"
args = "S_example.exe c " + filename
subprocess.call(args, stdout=True, stderr=True, shell=False)
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot open file:C:\Python27\application_rx_example\Debug\input.txt
```

Comment: i am getting  ERROR: Cannot open file:C:\Python27\application_rx_example\Debug\input.txt

How can i solve this issue..??

Comment: Create a file at that location?

Comment: Yes .File already created in that location.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem but have you tried changing all to double backslashes instead of single-double-single-double?

Comment: I changed it because \a ,\i are escape characters .Without this filename path will be replaced with escape characters .